# Linq retrive the parent object

Tags: c#, linq

Im using entityframework and the parent object `MyObject` already exist in my context (and childs loaded).

```cs
    public class MyObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Child> child { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Child2> child2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to make a condition on a `Child2` property with keeping an instance of the Parent object.

`var myFiletredMyObject = myObject.child.Where(c => c.child2.Any(c2 => c2.id == 1));`
This gives me back a collection of `Child` object, how can I do to get the parent : `MyObject` ?

Comment: Edited, sorry for that

Comment: Well, as per your class-strucure I can´t see any way to achieve this, as a `Child` has no clue on its parent-object. But isn´t `myObject` already the object you´re after?

Comment: @HimBromBeere In fact, I want to do this in order to keep only one child in the parent object

Comment: Why do you have two Child model classes in the first place?

Comment: Well, `var object=myObject;` Done.

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul I dont get this point, because i need 2 childs ? This is 2 "*-n" sql relations

Comment: @bolkayYou should re-read the question or explain me how you can make the conditions that i want to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've followed the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), then you should have written the relations between your tables as virtual properties.

> In entity framework, the columns of your tables are represented by non-virtual properties; the virtual properties represent the relations between your tables (one-to-many, many-to-many).

Furthermore: it is better to describe the one-to-many as an `ICollection<...>` instead of an `IEnumerable<...>`. This enables you to ask for the number of children, and to Add a Child, something that entity framework can translate into SQL easily.

So with a little change in your code, changes that will give you the same database (well, I've renamed the properties a little, to make it easier in my example)

```
public class Parent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    // every Parent has zero or more Children (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    // every Child is the child of exactly one Parent, using a foreign key
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}

    // every Child has zero or more Child2 (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Child2> Children2 { get; set; }
}

public class Child2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    // every Child2 belongs to exactly one Child, using foreign key
    public int ChildId {get; set;}
    public virtual Child Child {get; set;}
}
```

And the DbContext:

```
public class FamilyDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Child> Children {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Child2> Children2 {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough for entity framework to detect your tables, the columns in the tables and the relations between the tables (in this case: one-to-many).

Because of the odd plural of Child you might get an odd table name: Childs. To prevent this, you might want to use fluent API. Add to your DbContext:

```
public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder);
{
    // configure the one-to-many between Parent and Child using the foreign key:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
        .HasMany(parent => parent.Children)
        .HasRequired(child => child.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(child => child.ParentId);

    // configure the one-to-many between Child and Child2 using foreign key
    // make sure that the table gets a proper name
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().ToTable("Children")
         .HasMany(child => child.Children2)
         .HasRequired(child2 => child2.Child)
         .HasForeignKey(child2 => child2.ChildId);

    // the one-to-many relations are configured. Set the last table name
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child2>().ToTable("Children2");
}
```

**Back to your question**

If you've configured your classes the way that entity framework was meant, your query will be easy:

```
var myFilteredChildrenWithTheirParents = dbContext.Children
    .Where(child => ...)
    .Select(child => new
    {
        // select only the Child properties you really plan to use:
        Id = child.Id,
        Name = child.Name,

        Parent = new
        {   // again: select only the Parent properties you plan to use:
            Id = parent.Id,
            Name = parent.Name,
        },

        // no need for the foreign key, you already selected the value in Parent
        // ParentId = child.ParentId,
});
```

Comment: I did a Model base EntityFramework so this convention is already followed. I just wanted to put a very (too) simple case with my 3 classes.
Thanks for your answer, thats what i was looking for, great !

Answer (score 0):

Considering EntityFramework will return list of models from database you can filter your EF object like this.

```
var filterResult = myObject.Where(x => x.child.Any(a=>a.child2.Any(c2 => c2.id == 1))).ToList();
```

Filter Result will be of type **MyObject**.

if your Object of type  **MyObject**  you can use ternary operator to apply criteria.

```
var filterResult = myObject.child.Where(a => a.child2.Any(c2 => c2.id == 1)).ToList().Count > 0 ? myObject : null;
```

Comment: If you consider myObject as a IEnumerable (as DataSet for EF), this solution is the good one. and can be a workaround if i dont find another solution.
In my case myObject is already a MyObject type (from a previous request)

Comment: It just returns my initalial objet (myObject) without applying conditions

Comment: if condition satisfies it will return origional obj.otherwise it will return null